# Tratar JSON por Javascript

Tags: javascript

Após ajax, meu retorno do php é:

`[{"1":"4"},{"2":"3"},{"3":"7"}]`

Os dados são variaveis em quantidade e conteúdo.

Preciso trata-lo pelo javascript e converte-lo num array, neste formato:

```
var retorno = [
    [1, 4],
    [2, 3],
    [3, 7]
];
```

Estou tentando:

```
var parsed = JSON.parse(response);
var arr = [];
for(var x in parsed){
    arr.push(parsed[x]);
}
alert(arr);
```

`response` é a variavel com dados de retorno

Mas o resultado do alert é: `[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]`

Comment: Neste caso, vc está inserindo um objetct no array mesmo... parsed[x] será, por exemplo, {"1":"4"}, não ficou claro pra mim a saída que vc quer, vc quer um array com os indices ou um array com dois membros em cada linha do array?

Comment: Opa, o formato que preciso é o que está na var `retorno`, cada item do json numa linha do array. Vlw

Comment: e amigão, não entendi o que informou

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Criei um *array* dentro do `for` inserindo a chave e o valor da chave. Veja:

```js
var parsed = JSON.parse('[{"1":"4"},{"2":"3"},{"3":"7"}]');
var arr = [];
for(var x in parsed){    
  arr.push([parseInt(x)+1, parseInt(parsed[x][parseInt(x)+1])]);
}

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: @snniffer fiz uma alteração, apenas para simplificar! Se tiver mais alguma dúvida, só dar um toque aqui! =D

Answer (score 1):

acho que alguma coisa assim

```
var response = '[{"1":"4"},{"2":"3"},{"3":"7"}]';
var parsed = JSON.parse(response);
var arr = [];
parsed.forEach(function(pvalue,index,ar){
    for(var pname in pvalue){
        arr.push([pname,pvalue[pname]]);
    }
});
console.log(arr);
```